# groovy, string refuses to be a bigInt, is odd instead

Tags: java, groovy

I am losing my hair with Groovy lang, it has ruined 4 days for me in a row and it is counting.

What i need to do is to execete an external process, read stdout, get that value and convert it to big int. What i have

```
def str ='openssl x509 -in "'+ file + '" -serial -noout'    
def command = "cmd /c " + str;
def proc = command.execute();
proc.waitFor();
def response =  "${proc.in.text}"
def result = response.split('=')[1]
log.info result
// outputs: 7434F30AEE5F2001530C7F0C4844E9EE
log.info result.class.name
// outputs: java.lang.String
```

Ok, very cool, lets go on:

```
def big = new BigInteger(result.decodeHex())
```

No-no, cant be done:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: odd number of characters in hex
>   string

Meanwhile in another script:

```
def numb = '7434F30AEE5F2001530C7F0C4844E9EE'
log.info numb.class.name
// outputs : java.lang.String
b = new BigInteger(numb.decodeHex())
log.info b
// outputs : 154465376439281796222583609645190146542
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should trim your `result` from whitespaces, newlines and stuff like that - and after that, print out the number of characters in this string if they are even or still odd.

Comment: i am so sad, that the explanation was so simple

Comment: @Erki If you still have problems after doing what Smutje suggests then maybe the odd number is a 1 and the single-char string is being auto-converted to a char by one of the "Groovy Default Methods" you use. Your journey looks a lot like what I went through 4 to 6 years ago when I used Codehaus Groovy a lot, though I had less hair that I could lose.

Comment: yeah, the thing is that I am developing in SoapUI and there are not many debugging options available there.